# JQuery mobile listview refresh icon

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm changing the icon on list item (`'li'`) and the list is not refreshed. The code snapshot:

```js
var listview = $('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">');
...

var button = $('li#' + id, $.mobile.activePage);
button.attr('data-icon', 'check');

listview.listview('refresh');
```

However the list shows the old icon.

Please assist!

Answer (score 3):

It can be done like this:

```
$('#test-list li').buttonMarkup({ icon: "home" });
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/qgE6L/