# jquery mobile listview item icon refresh FAILED

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I wanna remove icon after listview itme is clicked:
[image]

`$('ul li#' + id).prop('data-icon', false);
listview.listview('refresh');` didn't work

Google found: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5108 and add:
`listview.trigger('create');` or `listview.children('li a').button();` fails too.

[JQuery mobile listview refresh icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354593/jquery-mobile-listview-refresh-icon) `$('li').buttonMarkup({icon : 'false'});` fails again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove classes `ui-btn-icon-right` and `ui-icon-plus`. You can do it directly using `.removeClass("ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-plus")` or use `.match` in case you have different icons used in the same *listview*.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("#listviewID li a").on("click", function () {
        $(this).removeClass(function (i, uiClass) {
            return (uiClass.match(/\S+-icon-\S+/) || []).join(' ');
        });
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nme4L80n/)**